# O que é um upsert?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Vi o termo ***UPSERT*** em um *blog* e gostaria de entender melhor o funcionamento.

- Ele designa que tipo de operação?
- Em quais situações pode ser utilizado?
- Tem a ver com *idempotência*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> O que é um upsert?

É um comando que insere um novo dado se não existe um com a mesma chave primária ou atualiza se a chave é encontrada, portanto nunca dá erro por não existir a chave como ocorre no `UPDATE` ou por já ter a chave quando faz um `INSERT`.

> Ele designa que tipo de operação?

É uma comando DML normal do SQL, em essência junta o `UPDATE` com o `INSERT` em um comando só.

Como gerou uma dúvida, um comando não é o mesmo que palavra-chave. Os DBs não costumam ter uma `UPSERT` e sim um comando que faz uma escolha automática entre o `INSERT` e `UPDATE`. Comando é o todo, com várias cláusulas.

> Em quais situações pode ser utilizado?

Sempre que o objetivo é colocar a informação no banco de dados e não importa se ela já existe ou não, mudando a semântica do que fazer conforme essa existência ou não.

> Tem a ver com idempotência?

Não sei se entendi o contexto do uso. Puramente não tem a ver porque toda alteração tem potencial de mudar o resultado final. Pode ser que em algum contexto seja considerado assim, mas estou só especulando.

Fui pesquisar e falam da idempotência da operação como um todo, não que ele seja, mas ele ajuda o resultado de uma tentativa de escrita ser. Não sei se isso é correto, eu precisaria refletir mais. Muitas vezes o pessoal usa termos sem pensar bem. Os argumentos que eu li não me convenceram inicialmente.

Talvez o termo esteja sendo usado no sentido de que nunca retorna erro (por causa de inexistência ou duplicidade, pode dar por outros motivos). Se mandar algo que já existe ele faz a operação de `UPDATE` e o resultado da operação é um acerto, e se mandar algo inexistente ele faz a operação de `INSERT` e o resultado da operação é um acerto. Nesse ponto é idempotente. Mas eu acho "forçar a barra" pra usar o termo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Maniero, eu li sobre essa relação com idempotência aqui nesse artigo, no caso se refere a um sistema de vende da ingressos: http://cloudingmine.com/idempotence-what-is-it-and-why-should-i-care/

Answer (score 4):

É um termo usado em banco de dados para falar sobre um comando, query ou api, que vai executar um `INSERT` ou  um `UPDATE`, de acordo com um condicional.

Exemplos:

> `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
>
> `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE`