# UPSERT ou UPDATE-INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, desempenho

Através [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324209/o-que-%C3%A9-um-upsert) senti a necessidade de pesquisar e entender um pouco sobre o *UPSERT*. Estava me perguntando *que bendito comando é esse? nunca vi..*

Encontrei algumas informações mas ainda não está claro pra mim pois não existe um "comando básico", tipo `UPSERT tabela (id=0, valor='nome')`, por exemplo.

Costumeiramente vejo códigos usando a seguinte estrutura:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tabela WHERE id = 0)
    UPDATE tabela SET campo = 2 where id = 0
ELSE
    INSERT INTO tabela (id, campo) VALUES (0, 1)
END
```

Sobre *upsert* encontrei [essa forma](https://sqltemuco.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/upsert-el-nuevo-comando/):

```
MERGE INTO tabela
USING (SELECT 0 AS id, 1 AS campo) AS reg
ON tabela.id = reg.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET campo = reg.campo
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT(id , campo)
     VALUES (reg.id, reg.campo)
```

Assim sendo, com relação a **performance**, qual forma devo utilizar? o `IF` que consulta a existência pelo identificador e define qual fluxo seguir (*insert* ou *update*) ou o `MERGE` (*upsert*) que condensa os dois comandos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você chama o segundo bloco de código na pergunta? Eu chamo de comando. Poderia ter indentação para ficar mais claro que é uma coisa só.

Quer dizer que não tem uma palavra-chave `UPSERT`? Ok, isso não é necessário, a não ser, talvez, para facilitar. Se fosse uma palavra-chave eu teria escrito com o estilo apropriado. Acho errado até escrever tudo em maiúsculo por conta da gramática.

O comando precisa realizar atomicamente e talvez idempotentemente (ainda não conclui isso, mas tem várias fontes dizendo, sem explicar, então não vou comprar tão fácil, já tentaram me explicar e não me convenceram, ficou explicação de dicionário) uma operação ou a outra.

O primeiro está em uma transação? Talvez possa ser considerado como `Upsert`, mas não um comando único. Isto não sei dizer. Se não estiver certamente não é e pode até gerar problemas, mesmo que raro. Imagino que o primeiro não é executado de forma isolada, então está tudo bem.

Cada banco de dados implementa como quiser, ou deixa de implementar. Até onde eu sei não tem um padrão no SQL ANSI, até porque se tem, fazem um péssimo trabalho nas implementações.

Se interfere na performance ou não é detalhe de implementação, mas deve mudar bem pouco, outras coisas fazem mais diferença, a interpretação do comando fará muito mais diferença do que ele em si. O primeiro pode ser mais rápido porque é mais simples *parseá-lo* e executá-lo, mas só especulando. Pode ser que no primeiro esteja ocorrendo uma duplicidade de verificação de existência e isso pode piorar bem a performance. Faça um teste em caso real. Pode mudar caso a caso.

O que eu sei é que alguns DBs enfrentam dificuldades para fazer certo e manter a performance, provavelmente por escolhas erradas anteriores.

Não sei se o `MERGE` tem é uma equivalência exata ao primeiro bloco, aí compará-los não faz sentido.

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: o meu ponto principal seria _"existir_ um comando (palavra-chave) com o nome upsert". Entendo que o `merge` funciona como esse _comando_ (e que sim, é um bloco único).

Comment: Achei válida sua resposta; realmente o primeiro bloco (`if`) tem operações separadas e talvez duplicidade de validação, mas ainda assim talvez tenha melhor performance que o segundo (segue a dúvida =p)

Answer (score 2):

Em relação a performance, creio que faz uma diferença quando se tem nativamente o UPSERT, como no banco de dados cassandra que o INSERT é um UPSERT, então ao dar INSERT como todo banco já tem que validar se já existe a chave, ele já decide ali naquela consulta se vai ser um update ou insert. Agora, se você tem que efetuar a consulta, como no caso do IF ou do MERGE, creio que não faça diferença significante.